# How to create dropdown list in OpenXava?

Tags: java, hibernate, drop-down-menu, pojo, openxava

how can we create the dropdown list type question in OpenXava? Let's say Gender is the question with (Male, Female, Other) with respective answers.

How can I declare the variable in the POJO class. Or do we have any hibernate annotations for the same.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your property as an enum, thus:

```
private Sex sex;
public enum Sex { MALE, FEMALE, OTHER }
```

OpenXava will generate a combo for that.

Comment: Yes, It is working as expected and I am able to save the data in database. But While searching OR editing an existing record I am getting an system error (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Unknown name value for enum class, com.test.dashboard.model.Sex), Why? How to resolve this?

Comment: Hi Precious, put the complete code of you class and the stacktrace produced in the Tomcat log in the OpenXava Help forum: https://sourceforge.net/p/openxava/discussion/419690/

Comment: @javierpaniza What will be persisted in database for a enum? A varchar like 'FEMALE' ?

Comment: The way an enum is stored in database is not OpenXava specific, but a JPA issue. Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252617/storing-enum-values-with-jpa