# Storing Enum Values with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enums

Say I have an enum:

```
public enum NotificationType {

    Store("S"),
    Employee("E"),
    Department("D"),
    All("A");

    public String value;

    NotificationType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I want to store `S` or `E` rather than `Store` or `Employee` in the database. Currently, I've mapped it in the entity as follows:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private NotificationType notificationType;
```

but unsure how to get what I want, if possible.

Comment: Just want to note, your enum is mutable, it's recommended to make enum fields `final`. And consider declaring the field `value` as `private` with `public` getter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare own user type to do the conversion between the strings and the enum you can find out more in this article:

http://javadata.blogspot.no/2011/07/hibernate-and-enum-handling.html

One small remark UserType is Hibernate specific. If you want to use JPA only. You need attribute converter. How to do that you can find here:

http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/

And one more link on Stackoverflow dealing with Atribute converters shows exact implementation of such.
[Is it possible to write a generic enum converter for JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564506/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-enum-converter-for-jpa)